# Add item to single page after pagination Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

After pagination in Laravel 5.1, I want add some item to few page

```
$data = Data::paginate(3);
```

Anybody have idea?

Comment: You want to add data to the page you are on, or to one(some) of the paginated pages?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)